# If $G$ has semidihedral Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ and an involution not conjugate to central involution in $S$. Existence of maximal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that it has a Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ that is a [semidihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasidihedral_group) and let $t$ be a noncentral involution in $S$. Assume that $t$ is not conjugate to the central involution in $S$, i.e. the central involution of $S$ is not in $t^G := \{ t^g : g \in G \}$.

> Then do we have a maximal subgroup $U$ of $G$ such that $t^G \cap U = \emptyset$?

Just that $t$ is not conjugate to the central involution in $S$ implies that we have some maximal subgroup in $G$ that has empty intersection with the conjugacy class of $t$; where should this maximal subgroup in $G$ come from?

Comment: You can deduce this from the Focal subgroup theorem. Let $S = \langle s,t \mid s^{2^n}=t^2=1, tst=s^{2^{n-1}-1} \rangle$ be semidihedral with $n \ge 3$. If $t$ is not conjugate in $G$ to the central involution $s^{2^{n-1}}$, then the focal subgroup is contained in $\langle s^2,ts \rangle$ and does not contain $t$.